# Whether there is a public key encryption system based on elliptic curve with the property of multiplication and addition homomorphism。

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I want to implement it on the intelligent contract and then do the development，because use paillier i cant genereate 1024bits key,so i try to find if there is exit a public key encryption system based on elliptic curve with the property of multiplication and addition homomorphism。

Comment: Are you looking for Paillier-like "multiplication", i.e. you can combine a ciphertext with some constant $c$ to get an encryption of $c$-times the original encrypted value or proper homomorphic encryption, i.e. you can combine two encrypted values to get an encryption of their product?

Comment: I want combine two ciphertext and get their the product of their plaintext,just like paillier E(m1*m2) = E(m1)^E(m2)

Comment: Paillier doesn't support that. It supports addition, i.e. you can combine $E(a)$ and $E(b)$ to get $E(a+b)$ and you can combine $c$ and $E(a)$ to get $E(ac)$.